# Confusion over $\iff$ and $\implies$ in basic set theory definitions of union and intersection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am working through Chapter 3 of Terence Tao's Analysis I on basic set theory. Doing the exercises has highlighted some gaps in my understanding.

This question is about one such gap.

Compare the following two examples of what I think are logically valid steps.

---

**Example 1**

$$\begin{align}x \in (A \cup B) &\iff (x \in A) \lor (x \in B) \\ \\ &\implies (x \in B) \lor (x \in B) \\ \\ & \implies x \in B \end{align}$$

The first line uses a $\iff$ biconditional because that is the definition (Axiom 3.5 in Tao's 4th edition).

The next line uses $A \subseteq B$ which is given by the exercise. It means $(x \in A) \implies (x \in B)$. Thus, we can replace $x \in A$ with $x \in B$.

But we can't replace $x \in B$ with $x \in A$, and this is the reason for the second line using $\implies$ and not $\iff$. **Question - is this correct?**

---

**Example 2**

$$\begin{align}x \in (A \cap B) &\iff (x \in A) \land (x \in B) \\ \\ &\implies (x \in A)\end{align}$$

I am happy with $P \land Q \implies P$ and also that $P \not \implies P \land Q$. This is why the second line uses a $\implies$ and not have a $\iff$. **Question - is this correct?**

---

Comment: That all looks good to me.

Comment: this is all correct for the reasons you stated

Comment: Example 1 is wrong. $x$ may  be an element of $A$, but not an element of $B$. Could this be a typo?

Comment: @DanChristensen Read the question. It is given that $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: @PeterSmith Looks to me like she is trying to prove $x \in (A\cup B) \implies x\in B.$

Comment: @DanChristensen Which is of course true (and provably so) if $A \subseteq B$. Read what the OP wrote.

Comment: @DanChristensen - The OP does mention that $A\subseteq B$ is given in the exercise, but only after they made use of the fact, so I do not blame you for missing it. @ Penelope, it is good practice to give all the relevant information *before* you make use of it, not throw it in afterwards.

Comment: @PaulSinclair OK. I guess I am used to initial assumptions being explicitly given at the BEGINNING of a proof.

Comment: I'm bothered by "replace $x \in B$ with $x \in A$." I used a proof by cases: (1) $x\in A$ or (2) $x\in B$ to prove: $x\in A\cup B ~\land~ A\subset B \implies x\in B.$

Comment: Thank you @RobArthan and RyRy_the_Fly_Guy for answering the question, and everyone else for their comments.