# Is this a legitimate substitution in FOL?

Tags: logic

Follow-up question to "Confusion over  $\iff$ and  $\implies$ in basic set theory definitions of union and intersection." [Confusion over $\iff$ and $\implies$ in basic set theory definitions of union and intersection.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4791907/confusion-over-iff-and-implies-in-basic-set-theory-definitions-of-union-an)

There we have:

> It means $(x \in A) \implies (x \in B)$. Thus, we can replace $x \in
> > A$ with $x \in B$.

Is this a legitimate substitution in FOL? It is assumed that $A\subset B$. I was able to obtain the required result using proof by cases.

Comment: Yes - in the presence of the hypotheses "$\forall y, y \in A \implies y \in B$", and "$x \in A \lor x \in B$", one can prove that $x \in B$, by applying [disjunction-elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination), [universal elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) and [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens). The details depend a bit on what the rules of inference are, and the format of the formal proofs.

Comment: Not substitution but a chain of inferences.

Comment: Substitution of formulas into contexts works with equivalent formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking whether or not you can substitute $B$ for $A$ in *any* FOL formula $\phi$, assuming it is true that $A \implies B$, and thereby obtain a statement $\psi$ that is implied by the original statement $\phi$, then the answer is no.

Consider:

$P \land Q$ implies $P$, but clearly $(P \land Q) \to R$ does not imply $P \to R$

Now, there is* a substitution principle/theorem involving *equivalences*: If $A \Leftrightarrow B$, then you can substitute $B$ for $A$ in *any* FOL formula $\phi$, and thereby obtain a statement $\psi$ that is implied by the original statement $\phi$. In fact, the result would simply be equivalent to the original, and therefore certainly be implied by it.

Comment: That is essentially what I am asking. In your example, should that be "does not imply $R\to P$"?

Comment: @DanChristensen  No, I have it right. When you substitute $P$ for $P \land Q$ in $(P \land Q) \to R$, you get $P \to R$